# Apply function for one item from dataframe to all other items

Tags: python, text-mining, sentence-similarity

I am examining similarity of text in Python. I have dataset with around 100 records and prepared a function for checking similarity - it has 2 arguments for 2 sets of words.

```
def getSimilarity(a, b):
    x = set(a)
    y = set(b)
    z = x.intersection(y)
    return float(len(z)) / (len(x) + len(y) - len(z))
```

My dataframe:

```
1 ['a','b','c','d']  other columns
2 ['a','h','e','f']  other columns
3 ['3','b','c','g']  other columns
4 ['y','b','c','z']  other columns
5 ['h','b','j','k']  other columns
```

... ...

I would like to create a method that will iterate over dataframe for given row, and will find out let's say 2 most similar records.
for example `checkSimilarity(1)` or `checkSimilarity(df['col'][1])` for index 1 in dataframe and will give us `[3, 4]` as the most similar.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: you can use `numpy` vectorize: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html